# Change string in native method

Tags: java, utf-8, java-native-interface, native

I use a native method to solve a string. But when return result I get an error

`JNI WARNING: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte 0xff`

This is my code:

```
jstring Java_com_example_helloworld_NativeLib_helloWorld(JNIEnv* env,
    jobject thiz, jstring src) {
    const char* mystring = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, src, (jboolean*) 0);
    printf("mystring: %s ", mystring);
    int length = sizeof(mystring) / sizeof(mystring[0]);
    char *result = (char*) malloc(length);
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result[i] = mystring[i] + 1;
    }
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, src, mystring);
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, result); 
}
```

Comment: UTF-8 is a multi-byte format, simply increasing a byte may give illegal  multibyte sequences. Also length is wrong. `sizeof(mystring)` will give the size of a pointer (4, 8). And `result` misses (room for) a `'\0'` to terminate a C string. Nevertheless great seeing someone delving into JNI

Comment: I want code and decode some string in Jni. What should I do?

Comment: Java strings are Unicode. Unicode codepoints are non-contiguous so there is no general concept of next character (`mystring[i] + 1`). Does your encoding have to result in a string or can it be Byte[]? Whatever you encoding algorithm you choose, it is unlikely that it can't be done in Java without JNI.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on Joop Eggen's comment:

You should use `strlen` to find the length of the string; currently you are computing the size of a pointer.

```
int length = strlen(mystring);
```

The other problem you have is that the last char in `result` should be 0 to indicate end of string:

```
char *result = (char*) malloc(length+1);
result[length] = 0;
```

A harder problem is dealing with UTF-8. Adding 1 to all chars will create invalid character sequences for some inputs. If you only need to support ASCII, a quick fix is doing the operation only for ASCII characters and leaving the rest as they are:

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (0 <= mystring[i] && mystring[i] < 0x7d)
        result[i] = mystring[i] + 1;
    else result[i] = mystring[i];
}
```

Comment: Perfect. One might UTF-8 decode the char[] into a int[] (or wide character wchar_t) Unicode code points.

Comment: @Joni Thank you. I usually work in java and don't know more about C so that's difficult to me.
Thank you so much.